# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la orientación y el tamaño de una hoja al usar la librería mpdf?

Tags: php, pdf, programación-funcional, mpdf

Llevo apenas 2 días trabajando con esta librería así que tengo muy poco conocimiento de cómo funciona. He buscado, pero no he logrado encontrar nada al respecto. Necesito imprimir un documento con una o muchas tablas (dinámicas) pero por el contenido, debe ser en hoja tamaño oficio (Legal) y no encuentro como modificar.

Comment: Has mirado esto https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-size-orientation.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación oficial](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-size-orientation.html) de `mpdf` puedes hacer esto:

```
<?php
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['format' => 'Legal']);

$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');

$mpdf->AddPage('L'); // Agregar una nueva página con orientación horizontal
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');

$mpdf->Output();
```

o esto:

```
<?php

// Definir un tamaño / formato de página horizontal predeterminado por nombre
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'A4-L']);

// Definir un tamaño / formato de página predeterminado por matriz: la página 
//tendrá 190 mm de ancho x 236 mm de alto
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'utf-8', [190, 236]]);

// Definir una página predeterminada utilizando todos los valores predeterminados 
//excepto "L" para la orientación horizontal
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['orientation' => 'L']);
```

Comment: Lo intenté, de la primera forma me coloca la hoja en horizontal, sin embargo aunque le cambie a Legal, sigue conservando el tamaño carta, lo mismo en el segundo caso.

Answer (score 1):

después de buscar un poco más, por fin lo encontré.

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['format' => 'Legal']);

$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');

$mpdf->AddPage('L'); // Adds a new page in Landscape orientation
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');

$mpdf->Output();
```

Lo obtuve directamente de la documentación oficial de mpdf, creo que no había ido más profundo por eso no lo había encontrado.

https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-size-orientation.html